# How do I choose the name of the root subdirectory when zipping?

Tags: zip

I want to zip up a directory named "foo" recursively.  But when I expand the zip, I want everything to be expanded into a "bar" directory.  My research shows this can be done if I rename "foo" to "bar" then zip it up, but that seems inconvenient.  Is there a way to just say, "zip foo but put everything in it inside a directory called bar"?

Comment: Does it have to be zip? GNU tar can easily do this.

Comment: @muru it has to be a .zip file, but that doesn't mean the `zip` command has to build it.

Comment: then you'd probably be best off looking into Python or Perl's zip modules